# Setting the shadow of a window in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, user-interface, window

I have created a custom window to override NSWindow. It works perfectly except for the fact that it has a shadow. I use [self setHasShadow:NO] to programatically set the shadow but it still remains. However if I check with [self hasShadow], it returns false.

The only way I seem to get the shadow to go away is if I turn shadow off in Interface Builder. Yeah, I realize this is okay, but I am curious about why the programatic setting doesn't override the Interface Builder setting even though other programatic settings do.

I am not allowed to post any code therefore please do not ask me to do so.

**Do I need to do anything in addition to [self setHasShadow:NO] to set the shadow of the window programatically?**

**EDIT:** Calling `[self setHasShadow:NO]` from `awakeFromNib` makes the shadow go away. However I want to remove the shadow directly from the constructor not `awakeFromNib`

Mac OSX Snow Leopard, Xcode 3.2.6

Comment: What happens if you put `[self setHasShadow:NO]` in `awakeFromNib`, instead of in your initialization?

Comment: @sudorm-rf I tried putting [self setHasShadow:NO] in awakeFromNib and that makes the shadow go away. But I would prefer if I could directly do this in the constructor. What could possibly be changing the setting in between the time the constructor is called and awakeFromNib is called?

Comment: Well, the problem is that IB configures your window *after* the initialization is called.  `awakeFromNib` is called after IB initializes your view.  So, (most) settings in IB will take precedence over the ones in your initializer.

Comment: @sudorm-rf But I have a variety of things that I call programatically in my constructor that are not overwritten by IB (ie. the deferred flag). I am curious about why [self:setHasShadow:NO] specifically is not being overrode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done if You call it in "awakeFromNib" or make borderless window like so:

```
- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect
        styleMask:(NSUInteger)windowStyle
          backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType
            defer:(BOOL)flag
{

self = [super initWithContentRect: contentRect
              styleMask: NSBorderlessWindowMask 
                backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered
                  defer: NO];

if(self)
{
    [self setHasShadow:NO];

    [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
    [self setOpaque:NO];
}   

return self;
}
```

** I don't know if You have titlebar. If You have You should use styleMask: NSTitledWindowMask if not NSBorderlessWindowMask

But If You **don't want to create borderless window** also it should work when You call from "awakeFromNib":

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    [self setHasShadow:NO];
}
```

I hope You choose for Your window class Your own writted class?? You can do this here:

[image]

Also You should write this to disable shadow if You use borderless window:

```
-(BOOL)hasShadow {
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: I have a borderless window as you mentioned and have selected my window class. However the shadow only goes away if I call [self setHasShadow:NO] from awakeFromNib. Why doesn't it work if it is called only from the constructor?

Comment: You should also write -(BOOL)hasShadow, look at my answer update at the bottom.